# Python networkx draw graph with scrollbars

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx

I have a networkx graph like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as Plot
...
UserGraph = nx.Graph()
users = get_users()
mapping = {}
for i in range(len(users)):
    user = create_user(users[i])
    UserGraph.add_node(user)
    mapping[user] = user.id

OutGraph = nx.relabel_nodes(UserGraph, mapping)
Plot.figure(1, figsize=(100, 100))
nx.draw_graphviz(OutGraph)
Plot.show()
```

This will make the output window very huge, but i need it, because there are many nodes in there. In fact I can't see the graph anymore.
How can I get scrollbars for the output window?
Or is it possible to scroll in and out somehow?

Comment: if you solved your own problem, pleas answer your own question.  Also removing the `matplotlib` because you are not actually using the library.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out that graphviz isn't made for drawing huge graphs, so I exported the graph as DOT-file and opened it in Gephi.
I think this could be a better solution to my problem.